# MySQL Cannot add foreign key constraint where data types are the same

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a table with a foreign key to a related table. I am getting the error 'Cannot add foreign key constraint' when trying to create this table however i checked the data type of both tables and they are the same. Is there any other reason why I could be getting this error?

Table:

[image]

SQL for table holding FK:

```
   CREATE TABLE messages
(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    subject varchar(50),
    message text,
    message_time datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    unread boolean DEFAULT true,
    sender varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(sender) REFERENCES users(username) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: Does `users` table have index on `username` column?

Comment: Please add create statement for `users`table.

Comment: users does have the username column as shown in the (poor) image. The table was created earlier, i don't have the create statement for the users table

Comment: Are there any other foreign key in your database? Are you using engine that supports them?

Answer (score 0):

You're sender_id and user_id should have same data type + size + same attribute i.e. UNSIGNED

Comment: My username column is varchar(16) and my sender (FK) is varchar(16) . This is why I can't see the issue here since they have the same datatype and size

Comment: I would suggest to use number over string when linking 2+ tables.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating the table with laravels migrate and it ran without error. Using the following:

```
    Schema::create('messages', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('subject', 50);
        $table->string('content');
        $table->boolean('unread')->default(true);
        $table->string('sender', 16);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('sender')->references('username')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Again I am still unsure what was different in the two columns such that they cannot be foreign keys..